# How to Reading 10 integers from user, and identifying second highest without using arrays?

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    //declare variables

    int numbers;
    int secondHighest;

    // create scanner to enter 10 digits

    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 10 digits: ");
    numbers = scanner.nextInt();



    for (numbers = 0; numbers > 10; numbers++);

    for (secondHighest =+ 0 ; secondHighest < 10; secondHighest++)
    System.out.print( secondHighest);
```

this how far I reached, I can have the user enter those 10 digits but having an issue figuring out how to get the program to identify which of these 10 numbers is the second-highest also worth mentioning that the numbers need to be written in one line as such:

Provide 10 integers: 67 -468 36 1345 -7778 0 34 7654 45 -666

The second largest is: 1345

Comment: I only see you asking the user for a single integer here?  Put the `nextInt()` in a loop, and use an `if` to check if the number is higher than the currently stored highest value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0, highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE, secondHighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            num = scanner.nextInt();
            if (num > secondHighest && num <= highest) {
                secondHighest = num;
            }
            if (num > highest) {
                secondHighest = highest;
                highest = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Second highest number is: " + secondHighest);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter an integer: 10
Enter an integer: -2
Enter an integer: 0
Enter an integer: 34
Enter an integer: -78
Enter an integer: 78
Enter an integer: 56
Enter an integer: 0
Enter an integer: 89
Enter an integer: -34
Second highest number is: 78
```

---

**[Update]**

If you want to enter all the numbers in the same line, do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0, highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE, secondHighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 10 integers: ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                num = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            if (num > secondHighest && num <= highest) {
                secondHighest = num;
            }
            if (num > highest) {
                secondHighest = highest;
                highest = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Second highest number is: " + secondHighest);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter 10 integers: 10 -3 24 0 56 -5 34 78 89 -6
Second highest number is: 78
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! How can I do that but have all the numbers in one line?                     
e.g: Enter 10 Integers: 12 41 21 43 47 14 69 40 35 18                                                      Second highest is 47

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int highestNumber = 0;
    int secondHighestNumber = 0;

    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter a digit: " + (i+1) + " of 10");
        int enteredNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        if (i == 0){
            highestNumber = enteredNumber;
            secondHighestNumber = enteredNumber;
        } else if ((enteredNumber < highestNumber) && (enteredNumber > secondHighestNumber)){
            secondHighestNumber = enteredNumber;
        } else if (enteredNumber > highestNumber){
            secondHighestNumber = highestNumber;
            highestNumber = enteredNumber;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(
            "Highest number is: " + highestNumber + '\n' +
                    "Second highest number is: " + secondHighestNumber
    );
}
}
```

@ Arvind Kumar Avinash
Your code is fine and things, but there's a problem. If the first number is the least one and the second number is highest one It doesn't work pretty well. Your code gives an output then:

```
Enter an integer: -120
Enter an integer: 998
Enter an integer: 994
Enter an integer: 25
Enter an integer: 12
Enter an integer: 36
Enter an integer: 256
Enter an integer: 398
Enter an integer: 578
Enter an integer: 22
Second highest number is: -120
```